# Маленький циклический сдвиг

Tags: c, алгоритм

На вход программе подается строка длиной не более 2000000 символов, состоящая из 0 и 1, при этом нулей в ней не более 2000. Требуется написать программу, которая находит такой циклический сдвиг строки, что его результатом будет лексикографически минимальная из всех возможных строка.

Если не сложно, напишите пожалуйста код, не могу найти ошибку.

> Входные данные: 010
>   Результат работы: 001
>
> Входные данные: 011001
>   Результат работы: 001011

Comment: Ну то есть фактически - найти самую длинную последовательность идущих подряд нулей, а если их несколько - минимальную про одинаковой длине.

Comment: @Akina Что означает выражение "минимальная последовательность нулей при одинаковой длине"? :)

Comment: @Akina чуть-чуть не так надо)

Comment: "Не могу найти ошибку" в чём именно?

Answer (score 3):

n - длина строки (до 2000000)
m - число нулей, идущих после единиц в зацикленной строке (до 2000)
Желаемая асимптотика O(n + m**2).

---

Для каждого нуля, идущего после единицы, определяем длину последовательности нулей, которая с него начинается и количество идущих за ней единиц (подряд). При этом строку считаем зацикленной. Эта штука считается за O(n).

Выбираем те нули, для которых получилась максимальная длина последовательности нулей. Для каждого из них составляем вектор количества нулей и количества единиц по всей строке, при этом по строке не ходим, а используем результат прошлого вычисления. Во всех векторах у чисел в чётных позициях (количество единиц) инвертируем знак. Это работает за O(m**2).

Из получившихся векторов выбираем лексикографически наименьший. Это тоже O(m**2).

Найденный вектор соответствует нулю, с которого надо начать циклический сдвиг строки.

Comment: угу, хотел такой же ответ писать) только можно не выбирать нули максимальной длины, а сразу инвертировать и искать максимум, ни на что не влияет но кода меньше.

Comment: @pavel, сразу инвертировать - это понятно, только непонятно как описать понятно в одном предложении, поэтому написал так в надежде, что он сам догадается. Сразу максимум - да, можно. Что-то я этот момент не продумал.

Answer (score 1):

Заводим массив, начально пустой. В нём будем хранить индексы. Также заводим переменную для количества, начально ноль.

### Первый проход.

Идём, ищем ноль. Нашли - заносим индекс начала в массив, потом идём дальше и считаем количество нулей подряд. Дойдя до единицы, сравниваем количество нулей подряд с текущим. Если меньше - удаляем индекс из массива, если равно, оставляем его там, если больше, удаляем все остальные индексы. Обход, есссно, зациклен.

Если по завершении обхода в массиве 1 элемент - это ответ. Иначе

### Второй проход.

Инкрементируем длину (она же - количество). Для каждого индекса смотрим элемент по смещению (индекс+длина), и удаляем из массива все индексы, где такой элемент единица. Затем инкрементируем длину и повторяем.

Когда в массиве останется один элемент - ответ получен.

Сложность считать лень, Навскидку будет O(n+m).

Comment: Что-то я второй пункт вообще не понимаю...

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну собственно то, что ты на втором этапе хочешь выполнять путём инверсии количества, сортировки и выбора минимума, я предлагаю выполнить простым сравнением - без сортировки, но отбрасывая бОльшие.

Comment: Так, вот есть строка длины 15 `001010010100101`, самая длинная последовательность нулей состоит из 2 нулей, индексы в массиве {0, 5, 10}. Что делать дальше? Вот вообще не понимаю, чего инкрементировать. Как изменятся вычисления, если я увеличу исходную строку добавив в конец 1? PS: Если строка делится на повторяющиеся подстроки, один элемент не останется никогда.

Comment: @Qwertiy Очень неудачную ты дал строку - она не имеет нерегулярностей, и является вообще наихудшим вариантом. *Если строка делится на повторяющиеся подстроки, один элемент не останется никогда.* Если строка состоит только из повторяющихся подстрок - да, сканирование будет идти, пока не будет пройдено всё кольцо. Если же есть нерегулярность - то массив будет терять элементы по мере того, как очередной индекс будет доходить до этой нерегулярности. PS. Я вот как раз сидел и рисовал наихудшие варианты...

Comment: @Qwertiy Пока у меня что-то получается, что сложность моего варианта вообще О(mn)... впрочем, у тебя мне тоже "Из получившихся векторов выбираем лексикографически наименьший. Это тоже O(m**2)." не очень нравится - сложность реальной сортировки строк/векторов зависит и от длины сравниваемых элементов, сортировать 1к строк по 2 символа или по 1к символов есть две большие разницы. Так что у тебя ещё как минимум это надо домножить на сложность сравнения двух строк/векторов, т.е. на (n/m).

Comment: У меня число векторов m, длина каждого вектора 2*m. Сортировать мне их не надо, только максимум, так что O(m*2*m) = O(m**2).

Comment: @Qwertiy Гм... надо обдумать.